# git Branch Without Commit - Revert Changes

Tags: git

This is a total noob git question, and I realized that people have asked similar questions, but I don't know what to do. I'm working on a project and wanted to try something out. It's not working, and now I want to go back.

At the point where I started my experiment, I did this:

> git branch experiment
> git checkout experiment

Then I did a bunch of stuff. And then I tried to go back with this:

> git checkout develop

But all of my experimental changes are still there. I can get back to earlier commits, but this loses much work.

What I realized is that I should have committed my changes before I branched. So, then I poked around in SourceTree to try to get a feel for what state my project is in. But now I'm in real trouble. According to SourceTree, the last commit was 12 hours ago. The uncommitted changes show only two very minor modifications that I made about 8 hours ago. I seem to have lost the last 8 hours of my work. It's the same on both branches.

Am I screwed now? Is there a way that I can I get back to the point at which I branched? Thank you.

Comment: Have you also checked the Experiment branch?

Comment: Yes. They both show the same status.

Comment: I read the git article: _note that if your working directory or staging area has uncommitted changes that conflict with the branch you’re checking out, Git won’t let you switch branches. It’s best to have a clean working state when you switch branches. There are ways to get around this (namely, stashing and commit amending) that we’ll cover later on, in Stashing and Cleaning_

Comment: I think it is strange that you could easily create a branch with uncommited changes

Comment: @KevinWallis No, that’s a feature for situations where you started some work but forgot to create a feature branch. Git allows you to freely switch branches with uncommitted changes if while switching the branch the modified files are not touched.

Comment: @poke thx for the hint

Comment: Uncommitted changes in the working directory do not live on any branch. They are branch-less, so-to-say. Only committed changes belong to a branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are screwed, but the good thing is you will learn from this mistake. When you are working with Git: `commit` frequently and `stash` when you switch context.

In your example you made some changes for example you modified `foo` and created `bar`. You can see the change before your experiment starts:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
        new file:   bar    
Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   foo
```

At this point if you create a new `branch` and switch on it, nothing will me modified neither on you `working directory` or your `index` since the new branch `experiment` points to the very same commit as master `master` do.

```
$ git checkout -b experiment
A       bar
M       foo
Switched to a new branch 'experiment'

$ git status
On branch experiment
Changes to be committed:
        new file:   bar    
Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   foo
```

So from here if you make changes you will loose your previous work. That said, this is not totally true because `bar` is on the index (green color when doing `git status`). If you modify `bar` your notice a change on your working directory, but the previous version remains on the index:

```
$ echo "bar" >> bar
$ git status
On branch experiment
Changes to be committed:
        new file:   bar
Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   bar
        modified:   foo
```

The two best solutions to keep track of your changes are:

1. Commit frequently on dummy branches.
2. Use [git stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) to switch between   contexts.

In your case you would have committed your changes on a dummy branch before starting your experiment:

```
$ git checkout -b previous_changes 
$ git commit -am "Something I want to keep"
$ git checkout -b experiment head@{1}
do some changes...
```

Answer (score 0):

> What I realized is that I should have committed my changes before I branched.

Yes, when you have uncommitted changes and you switch to a new branch, then those uncommitted changes are carried over and are still there while you are on your new branch. Since they are not committed, those changes do not belong to a branch or even the repository, so you cannot restore those.

If you then continued the work on the new branch, you ultimately modified those changes, possibly even committed them or reverted them. At this point, they are lost.

Changes that are never added to the repository do not belong to the repository and Git does not know about them. So unfortunately, if you cannot restore them from the actually committed changes you did on your new branch, they are lost.

Answer (score 0):

git reset --hard Will remove all your changes

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).